# NSLayoutConstraint behaving differently when drawing to NSBitmapImageRep

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nslayoutconstraint

I have this control called [ITNavigationView](https://github.com/iluuu1994/ITNavigationView) on Github.

It's smoothly animating from one `NSView` to another by caching and adding them to a `NSImageView`.
When caching the view, a subview centred in the x axis will be pulled exactly 1 pixel to the right.
If I instead add a leading constraint, this doesn't happen.

How can I prevent this from happening?

To cache the view, I'm using this code:

```
- (NSImage *)imageOfView:(NSView *)view {
    [view layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
    [view setNeedsUpdateConstraints:YES];
    [view updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeeded];

    NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [view bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:view.bounds];
    [view cacheDisplayInRect:view.bounds toBitmapImageRep:rep];

    return [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[rep CGImage] size:view.bounds.size];
}
```

---

### EDIT

Also worth noting is that this only happens when the superview has an odd width.

Comment: have you tried locking focus on an NSImage of correct size and calling the views `drawRect:` method?

Comment: @BradAllred This will unfortunately not work for most layer-backed views.

Comment: did you try anyway? I would have though the drawing methods do more or less what the `cacheDisplayInRect:` method does. what about the `renderInContext:` method of `CALayer`? Doesn't work with some kinds of layers/transforms/filter, but you don't specify any of that.

Comment: @BradAllred I actually have not tried it yet. I might consider it if there's absolutely no way around.

Comment: I know it's been a long time... but did you figure out why the subview moved by 1px?

Comment: @jtbandes I can't even recall ever having asked this question. Sorry...